# Regex capture everything between start word until end specific end word

Tags: regex

I would like to capture everything from `Session Appointment` until found specific word `Billing`

```
Session Appointment
Appointment Details
Date: XXXXX
Time: XXX am
Type: XXXXXX
Service: XXXXXX
Item: *XXXXXX*
Total price: XXXXX

Date: XXXX
Time: XXX am
Type:XXXX
Service: XXXX
Item: *XXXXXX*
Total price: XXXXX
Subtotal: XXXX
Discount: XXXX
Total: XXX
Booking Fee Amount XXX
Balance Amount XXXX
Summary
Status Amount
Deposit 
Pending payment XXX
Billing address Houston
```

This what i used but its only capture until `Total:`

**Regex :**
`(Session Appointment[^B]+)(?=\n)`

Answer (score 1):

If you just need it as raw string is more a question of configuring the regex engine correctly.

`(Session Appointment).*(Billing)` should match everything between *Session Appointment* and *Billing*. What you need, however, is to match in multiple lines.

Setup your regex engine to match a new line with `.`.

https://regex101.com/r/paI7nT/1

Comment: Be aware though, that this might overrun multiple blocks. The dot-star in singleline mode matches everything up to the end and then backtracks until it finds `Billing`. No matter how many other `Billing`s might be further up.

Comment: @Jan yup. That is true. One could add `?`, like `.*?` to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
^Session\ Appointment
.+?
^Billing\ address
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/XJjxcu/1/) and mind the different modifiers (`multiline`, `singleline` and `verbose`, that is).

Answer (score 1):

The reason the pattern `(Session Appointment[^B]+)(?=\n)` matches until Total: XXX is because the next line starts with Booking.

`[^B]+` matches any char except a `B` and the positive lookahead `(?=\n)` asserts what is directly on the right is a newline which is true for the line that starts with Booking.

If you want to match (note that for a match only you don't need the capturing group), you could match all the following lines that do not start with Billing:

```
^Session Appointment.*(?:\r?\n(?!Billing\b).*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3OyaGw/1)

If you want to match Billing as well, you could add `\r?\nBilling` after the pattern.

Comment: Oh, I see....Thanks for the suggestion. So if i want to capture all match the pattern start with  `Item`. What should i do?

Comment: @Muqri Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/0iDyA7/1

Comment: No, this is a different question...I only want to capture `Item` details only. So based on the example above, there is two  `Item` details. I want to capture both of it

Comment: @Muqri Then you could use it like this https://regex101.com/r/f8qSwP/1

Comment: Oh, I see..Thanks again really appreciate your help :)